# my program works on the chrome browser but not on chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, opencv, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to extract all the information of the game bubbleshooter from my browser window. It works when I try to extract it on the normal chrome browser but when I try to use selenium and chromedriver it doesn't work anymore. Let me be more specific, I am trying to extract the current and next ball from the game window, [image]

As you can see it detects the blue ball, but when I run the same environment in chromedriver  It doesn't [image]

Is there something I'm missing about chromedrivers ? I am using chrome version 109.0.5414.75 and so is my chromedriver

Some extra information

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.bubbleshooter.net")
```

this is how I use the chromedriver, I use OpenCV to analyze the image and pyautogui to take the screenshot. I'm not sure if the code is relevant here but If someone asks I can upload it

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer me

the code:

```py
    def extract_current_next_ball(self,image):
        colour_dictionary = {
            1: [253,239,1], # cyan
            2: [180,10,171], # purple
            3: [1,228,227], # yellow
            4: [33,241,1], # green
            5: [213,17,1], # blue
            6: [0,7,227] # red
        }
        x_locations = []
        for key, val in colour_dictionary.items():
            colour = np.array(val)
            lower_colour = colour - 15
            upper_colour = lower_colour + 15
            lower_colour[lower_colour < 0] = 0
            upper_colour[upper_colour > 255] = 255
            components = cv.inRange(image,lower_colour,upper_colour)
            # cv.imshow('components',components)
            # cv.waitKey()
            (num_labels, _labels, stats, _centroids) = cv.connectedComponentsWithStats(components, 4) # step 4
            for i in range(num_labels):
                x = stats[i, cv.CC_STAT_LEFT]
                if (x > 0):
                    x_locations.append((x, key))
        if (len(x_locations) == 0):
            return [1,1]
        max_x = max(x_locations,key=lambda x: x[0])
        min_x = min(x_locations,key=lambda x: x[0])
        current_colour = max_x[1]
        next_colour = min_x[1]
        return [current_colour,next_colour]
```

With this code I loop over all the different colours and try to find anything that matches that range, I then store the leftmost coordinate of the found component, and for the next ball I use the minimum value, and for the current ball the maximum value

Comment: Please share your code. Currently this question is missing basic details

Comment: on a sidenote, maybe give Playwright a try instead, which uses Chrome's own devtools protocol instead of needing webdriver.